# GeoMesa and lambda data store

Tags: geomesa

GeoMesa provides a lamda data store based Accumulo and Kafka (http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/current/user/lambda/index.html). But it also provides Storm and Spark support for offline and online analytics. Can you please list some use cases for the GeoMesa lamda data store? For example, what advantages does it provide for GeoServer?

Answer (score 3):

The GeoMesa Lambda DataStore is a definitely an 'advanced' feature.  If you have a datatype which is likely to receive frequent updates before it is persisted permanently to the database, then the Lambda DataStore may be a good fit.

As a concrete example (and applicable to me since I'm posting from a train:)), consider having a summary layer for a train trip.  While the train is going, one would want to update the summary for a given piece of data.  On the other hand, once the train has completed its trip, then the record would no longer updated.

A traditional/easy GeoMesa approach would be to write a piece of streaming software which writes the updates to a GeoMesa Kafka datastore.  Once a voyage is complete, then the streaming application could write to Accumulo or HBase.  An application looking to query the live updates and historical records would need to coordinate across two layers (one Kafka layer and one persistent database layer).

The Lambda datastores allows for all the writes to happen to the Lambda Datastore.  As the record is receiving updates, the record is handled in Kafka.  When the track updates timeout, the record is persisted to Accumulo.  In GeoServer, the Lambda datastore can be queried for records from the live and historical point of view together.  (As a detail, one can use a view parameter to restrict a query to either the transient or persistent part of the Lambda datastore.)